# Why do CSP implementations only cover channels?

Tags: clojure, lua, go, occam-pi

In the book about [Communicating Sequential Processes](http://www.usingcsp.com/cspbook.pdf) a lot of time is spent defining events, which have no direction and can involve multiple independent processes.

Only in chapter 4 are channels introduced, which are directed and involve 2 processes.

Yet all implementations of CSP including occam, Go, LuaCSP and clojure.core.async only implement channels.

Even though most practical problems can be solved with (broadcast) channels, I wonder why the book spends so much time on them while nobody uses them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Occam-pi, barriers are an important adjunct to channels. With a barrier, each enrolled process waits on the barrier until they have all done so. At this point they are all released. This is an example of a non-channel form of CSP event.

Occam-pi also has an extended rendezvous using channels. This is a quite different pattern of usage of channels, very similar to the rendezvous in Ada.

Comment: Is this the same concept as CyclicBarrier in Java? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html

Comment: I think they're broadly similar in concept. I don't know whether they're the same in fine detail. The Occam-Pi barrier has a highly efficient implementation (as are all of its synchronisation primitives).

Answer (score 9):

Well first of all the book [*happened before*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happened-before) the implementations. Therefore your question is better formulated as:

> Why does no implementation of CSP put a major focus on events even though the book emphazises them greatly.

Basically, making events a first-class citizen of a language gives it a certain usage specificity that would probably be too narrow for a [general purpose programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_programming_language).

Additionally, you can easily implement events on channels (and other constructs), in case you are into [event driven programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming).

Comment: This latter remark is tautologous. CSP and channels naturally provide an event-driven style. The difference is that channels *do not* require callbacks to handle events.

Comment: It's much more locking/unlocking than events. The thing transmitted through a channel can be anything.